# How to measure CPU running time and wall clock running time of a function, separately, as Python code (not from terminal)?

Tags: python, performance

I'm looking for a way to measure function performance in Python, separating wall clock and CPU time.

I've looked into the python profilers, but they seem to be designed to scan a program and not functions alone. From http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html :

> Note The profiler modules are designed to provide an execution profile for a given program, not for benchmarking purposes (for that, there is timeit for reasonably accurate results). This particularly applies to benchmarking Python code against C code: the profilers introduce overhead for Python code, but not for C-level functions, and so the C code would seem faster than any Python one.

I then tried the timeit module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html , but it doesn't seem to support separation of CPU and wall clock time. As I understand, it just measures total run time.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
$ time python yourprogram.py

real    0m1.028s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
```

But instead of calling it from command line, I need to call it from python code.

Something like system.time() in R:

```
print(system.time(replicate(repeats, factorialRecursive(150))))
 user  system elapsed 
0.041   0.001   0.041
```

How can I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `resource` module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/resource.html#resource-usage) houses `getrusage`, which should allow you to retrieve user, system, and wall-clock time separately, just as the `time` command does.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use that module to measure the running time of a function. I've tried usage = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF) inside the function i want to measure and then calling the ru_stime and ru_utime fields, but the times add up between different function calls. Do you know how to do it? I created the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19204740/1690799