# How to use the resource module to measure the running time of a function?

Tags: python, performance

I want to measure the CPU running time and wall clock running time of functions using Python code.

The resource module was suggested here: [How to measure CPU running time and wall clock running time of a function, separately, as Python code (not from terminal)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19204618/1690799)

Here is the module documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html

The problem is that:

1) I can't figure out how to use it to measure the running time of a function.

2) I don't know how to extract that information from the object returned.

How do I do this?

Comment: Call `getrusage()` before and after the thing you want to time.  Subtract the corresponding fields you care about to get elapsed differences.  The fields can be extracted by index (`result[0]`, 1, 2, ..., `result[15]`) or - with a recent enough Python - via attribute access (`result.ru_utime`, etc).  Check to make sure your system supplies the precision you need.  Millisecond and microsecond resolutions are, I think most common.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call [`getrusage`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource.getrusage) before and after executing the function, subtract the fields you care about, and you're done. Since `resource` doesn't do wall time, you'll need to use a separate function for that.

You can wrap that up in a helper function, or even a decorator, like this:

```
import datetime
import functools
import resource
import sys

def timed(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        r0 = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
        t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
        retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
        r = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
        t = datetime.datetime.now()
        sys.stderr.write('{}: utime {} stime {} wall: {}\n'.format(
            func.__name__,
            datetime.timedelta(seconds=r.ru_utime-r0.ru_utime),
            datetime.timedelta(seconds=r.ru_stime-r0.ru_stime),
            t-t0))
        return retval
    return wrapper

@timed
def myfunc(i):
    for _ in range(100000000):
        pass
    return i*2

print(myfunc(2))
```

This will print out something like:

```
myfunc: utime 0:00:03.261688 stime 0:00:00.805324 wall 0:00:04.067109
4
```

If you want more than a couple fields, you probably want to subtract all of the members of the rusage results, but since these are all int or float, that's easy:

```
rdiff = resource.struct_rusage(f1-f0 for f0, f1 in zip(r0, r))
sys.stderr.write('{}: utime {} maxrss {} nsignals {} etc.\n'.format(
    datetime.timedelta(seconds=rdiff.r_utime),
    rdiff.ru_maxrss,
    rdiff.ru_nsignals))
```